# For a ring of n tangent circles inscribed within the perimeter of a larger circle, calculate radius or diameter of circles or n

Tags: circles

***Update:** K. Jiang solved for n, so I updated my question here below to now have all of the working formulas for easy reference to others.*

**Original Question:** I have the following documented below correctly, but I'm having trouble solving for **n** because it's the denominator within sine. Can someone help me solve for **n** using $R = r ⋅[\sin(π ÷ n) + 1] ÷ \sin(π ÷ n)$?
Thanks

**These Are All Working Formulas Now:**

$n$ = the number of small circles
$r$ = the radius of the small circles
$R$ = the Radius of the large perimeter circle formed by the outer ring of small circles
$d$ = the diameter of the small circles
$D$ = the Diameter of the large perimeter circle formed by the outer ring of small circles

$$\boxed{r = R \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) + 1}}$$
$$\boxed{d = D \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) + 1}}$$

$$\boxed{R = r \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) + 1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}}$$
$$\boxed{D = d \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) + 1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}}$$

$$\boxed{n = \frac{\pi}{\arcsin(\frac{r}{R - r})}}$$
$$\boxed{n = \frac{\pi}{\arcsin(\frac{d}{D - d})}}$$
**Note:** the Radians function within Excel is **not** used for these formulas.
***Source:** http://www.had2know.com/academics/inner-circular-ring-radii-formulas-calculator.html

**K. Jiang** solved for n*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the right triangle formed when we connect the center of the large circle, a center of a small circle, and one of the two closest intersection points between two small circles. We know that the central angle in the right triangle is $\frac{\pi}{n},$ as you have noted. The far side has length $r,$ and the hypotenuse has length $R - r.$ Thus, we have the relation
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{r}{R - r}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{n} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{R - r}\right),$$
and we have the solution
$$\boxed{n = \frac{\pi}{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{R - r}\right)}}.$$

Comment: Thank you. This solves it.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!